# JRebel maven multi-module

Tags: java, jrebel, javarebel

How I can configure JRebel for multi-module maven project? For now, I added JRebel plugin to my parent `pom.xml` and I generated several `rebel.xml` *files* (*one `rebel.xml` per child module*) using `jrebel:generate` command. Is it correct behavior to generate several `rebel.xml` files for each module?

EDIT: In final all my modules will be collected at single EAR. So it mean I need to remove `JRebel-maven-plugin` from parent `pom.xml` and declare it only for pom.xml of EAR module of my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every 'artifact' that gets generated needs to have it's own rebel.xml file associated with it. If you look at the contents of rebel.xml it simply points to where JRebel can find the source directories, and these are generated to absolute paths by the maven plugin for ease of use.

I would be sure to put the JRebel plugin in a separate profile that is only active on development machines so you don't get these files generated for production.

For the ear, you don't need to remove the plugin. I don't think it will hurt anything, you just wont get much benefit from it. JRebel will find the rebel.xml files for all the separate jars/wars and use those as needed.

So in short, you are adding them in the correct spots.

Comment: ok, thanks. So it better to declare `jrebel-maven-plugin` in _parent_ `pom.xml`, but move it to separate `development` profile?

Comment: That's how I do it currently. This way it wont be active on build servers, or for people that dont have JRebel installed. (Note: It wont't hurt anything if it's there, but I try to keep extra stuff out of deployed items if possible)